# Using loop to insert multiple row in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a temp table to store some data for calculating payroll. Data is related to many tables and is a long query logic.

This stored procedure is to get some data from other tables then insert to `PayrollTemp` table for later use. It needs 3 parameters: the start and end date, and the `EmployeeID` (EmpID) for the main query and the nested queries.

So whenever we run this stored procedure, we only get

> (1 row(s) affected)

My question is how to use loop in SQL Server to pass every `EmployeeID` (EmpID) sequentially to store procedure in order to insert every record into the `PayrollTemp` table.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PayrollTemp_Init]
@startDate date, @endDate date, @EmpID int

AS

INSERT INTO dbo.PayrollTemp([EmpID],[BasicSalary],[Allowance],[W_Hrs],[W_days],[OT150Hrs],[OT200Hrs],[OT300Hrs],[Night130Hrs],
[NightOT150Hrs],[NightOT200Hrs],[NightOT300Hrs],[WeekdayDutyDays],[WeekendDutyDays],[OtherEarning],[SI],[HI],[UI],[UnionFee],[DependentDeduction],[OtherDeduction])
        select e.Id,e.BasicSalary,e.Allowance,
        (select SUM(ts.NormalHours) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID)W_Hrs,
        (SELECT
           (DATEDIFF(dd, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
          -(DATEDIFF(wk, @startDate, @endDate) * 2)
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @startDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @endDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))W_days,
        (select SUM(ts.OT150Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)OT150Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.OT200Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)OT200Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.OT300Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)OT300Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.Night130Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)Night130Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.NightOT150Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)NightOT150Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.NightOT200Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)NightOT200Hrs,
        (select SUM(ts.NightOT300Hrs) from TimeSheetA ts where EmpID=@EmpID and TimeSheetDate between @startDate and @endDate)NightOT300Hrs,

        (select count(EmpID)WeekdayDuty from NightDutySchedule where DATENAME(DW,DutyDate) not in('Saturday','Sunday') and DutyDate between @startDate and @endDate and EmpID=@EmpID)WeekdayDutyDays,
        (select COUNT(EmpID) from NightDutySchedule where DATENAME(DW,DutyDate)='Saturday' or DATENAME(DW,DutyDate)='Sunday' and DutyDate between @startDate and @endDate and EmpID=@EmpID)WeekendDutyDays,
        (select SUM(EarningAmount) from EarningDetails where EarningDate between @startDate and @endDate and EmpID=@EmpID)OtherEarning,
        (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
            WHEN  'False' THEN
            e.BasicSalary*0.08
            ELSE 0 end 
          )SI,
          (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
            WHEN  'False' THEN
            e.BasicSalary*0.015
            ELSE 0 end 
          )HI,
          (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
            WHEN  'False' THEN
            e.BasicSalary*0.01
            ELSE 0 end 
          )UI,
          (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
            WHEN  'False' THEN
            case  when e.BasicSalary > 4000000 or e.BasicSalary = 4000000 then  20000   else 15000 end
            ELSE 0 end 
          )UnionFee,
          (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
            WHEN  'False' THEN
                e.Dependants * 3600000
            ELSE 0 end 
          )DependentDeduction,
         (select SUM(DeductionAmount) from DeductionDetails where DeductionDate between @startDate and @endDate and EmpID=@EmpID)OtherDeduction
          from Employee e where e.Is_Active='True' and e.Foreigner='False' and e.Id=@EmpID

   declare @startDate date, @endDate date, @EmpID int
    set @startDate='2015-09-01'
    set @endDate='2015-09-30'
    set  @EmpID='3'
    select e.Id,e.BasicSalary,e.Allowance,SUM(ts.NormalHours)W_Hrs,
    (SELECT
               (DATEDIFF(dd, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, @startDate, @endDate) * 2)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @startDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @endDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))W_days,
        SUM(ts.OT150Hrs)OT150Hrs,SUM(ts.OT200Hrs)OT200Hrs, SUM(ts.OT300Hrs)OT300Hrs,SUM(ts.Night130Hrs) Night130Hrs,
        SUM(ts.NightOT150Hrs)NightOT150Hrs,SUM(ts.NightOT200Hrs)NightOT200Hrs,SUM(ts.NightOT300Hrs)NightOT300Hrs,
        (SELECT COUNT(case 
                WHEN DATENAME(DW,sch.DutyDate) not in('Saturday','Sunday') THEN
                    1
                ELSE 0 end 
              )WeekdayDutyDays,

        (SELECT COUNT(case 
                WHEN DATENAME(DW,sch.DutyDate)  in('Saturday','Sunday') THEN
                    1
                ELSE 0 end 
              )WeekendDutyDays,
        SUM(ed.EarningAmount)OtherEarning,
        (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
                WHEN  'False' THEN
                e.BasicSalary*0.08
                ELSE 0 end 
              )SI,
              (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
                WHEN  'False' THEN
                e.BasicSalary*0.015
                ELSE 0 end 
              )HI,
              (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
                WHEN  'False' THEN
                e.BasicSalary*0.01
                ELSE 0 end 
              )UI,
              (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
                WHEN  'False' THEN
                case  when e.BasicSalary > 4000000 or e.BasicSalary = 4000000 then  20000   else 15000 end
                ELSE 0 end 
              )UnionFee,
              (SELECT case e.Is_Probation
                WHEN  'False' THEN
                    e.Dependants * 3600000
                ELSE 0 end 
              )DependentDeduction,
             SUM(ded.DeductionAmount) OtherDeduction

    from Employee e 
    inner join TimeSheetA ts
    on e.Id=ts.EmpID and e.Is_Active='True' and e.Foreigner='False' 
    inner join NightDutySchedule sch
    on e.Id=sch.EmpID and sch.DutyDate >= @startDate and sch.DutyDate <= @endDate
    inner join  EarningDetails ed
    on e.Id=ed.EmpID and ed.EarningDate >= @startDate and ed.EarningDate <= @endDate
    inner join DeductionDetails ded
    on e.Id= ded.EmpID and ded.DeductionDate >= @startDate and ded.DeductionDate <= @endDate
```

I modifed to use inner join statement but when I excute , it display the error like this:

```
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
Incorrect syntax near '@endDate'.
```

Line 62 is: on e.Id= ded.EmpID and ded.DeductionDate >= @startDate and ded.DeductionDate <= @endDate (it is the last one, why?)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Correlated subquereis are a horrible practice, learn to use joins.

Comment: Since you are only sending in one employee id why would you expect to get more than one record inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Cursor: [MSDN - Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180169(v=sql.120).aspx)

Some example code:

```
DECLARE cursorName
CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT a,b FROM table WHERE a > 1
DECLARE @a int
DECLARE @b varchar(10)
OPEN cursorName
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName
INTO @a,
    @b

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )  BEGIN
--Code and procedure you want to call with @a and @b for each row
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName
INTO @a, @b
END
CLOSE cursorName
DEALLOCATE cursorName
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! It is very kind of you! I'll try it.

Comment: Very bad idea. This can be done in set-based fashion.

Comment: it is a bad algorithm idea from the author, but my answer is just the way how to do it, i dont say it is better or worse, it is what he asks for, thanks for voting -1 when the answer is correct :)

Comment: Please do not vote down for any helps . I'm new to SQL so I need to learn everything from you. Please give me the instruction instead of arguments.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I try to use inner join but unsessessfully for this case. So the best thing is to use cursor . Very fast!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it all at once and join to the employees table rather than sending in the employee id?

Of course if you want it to be performant at all, you need to completely rework the proc to use joins instead of correlated subqueries.

You desperately need to read this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)